# difficulty dealing with the reusability of the collection view cell.

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4

I am trying to create a seating plan using the collection view. In that each seat will have a specific number that means that each cell will have a label that displays the seat number. I am using custom collection view layout to create a seat map and the seat map is 2 way scrollable. Every thing goes well untill the seat map gets scrolled. once the seat map is scrolled the values of the seat numbers are being changed. I know that it is because of the reusability of the collection view cells but i can't find a way out. I tried to search for answer in stack but nothing is working for me. please help..

here is my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var seatNo = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    // func for number of section in collection view
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            seatNo = 1
        }
        cell.assignSeat(seat: seatNo)
        seatNo += 1
        cell.seatNumber.text = "\(cell.seat ?? 0)"
        return cell
    }

}
```

and here is my collection view cell :

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
  @IBOutlet weak var seatNumber: UILabel!
    var seat: Int?
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        seatNumber.text = ""
        seat = 0
    }
    func assignSeat(seat: Int) {
        self.seat = seat
    }
}
```

and if needed here is the code for the custom Collection View Layout:

```
class CustomCollectionLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

        // var for cell height
        var CELL_HEIGHT: Double!

        //Variable for cell width
        var CELL_WIDTH: Double!

        // Variable for the status bar height
        let STATUS_BAR = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

        // Array to store the cell attributes
        var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        //variable to define the content size
        var contentSize = CGSize.zero

        // another variable to store the cell atributes
        var cellAttrsDictionary = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // variable to store the cell padding
        var cellPadding: Double!

        // func that defines the collection view content size
        override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize{
            return self.contentSize
        }

        // func to prepare the collection view
        // how the cells are to be mapped is defined in this function
        override func prepare() {

            // assigning the values to the variables
            CELL_HEIGHT = 44
            CELL_WIDTH = 44
            cellPadding = 2

            // Cycle through each section of the data source.
            if collectionView?.isDragging == false{
                if collectionView!.numberOfSections > 0 {
                    for section in 0...collectionView!.numberOfSections-1 {

                        // Cycle through each item in the section.
                        if collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) > 0 {
                            for item in 0...collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section)-1 {

                                // storing the index of the current cell
                                let cellIndex = NSIndexPath(item: item, section: section)

                                // defining the x and y coordinates for the other cells
                                let xPos = Double(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                                let yPos = Double(section) * CELL_HEIGHT

                                //creating the frame for the cell
                                let frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)

                                //providing the padding
                                let cellFinalAttribute = frame.insetBy(dx:CGFloat(cellPadding) ,dy:CGFloat(cellPadding))

                                //storing the cellattributes in the array
                                let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: cellIndex as IndexPath)
                                cellAttributes.frame = cellFinalAttribute
                                cellAttrsDictionary.append(cellAttributes)
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

                // Update content size.
                let contentWidth = Double(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) * CELL_WIDTH
                let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections) * CELL_HEIGHT
                self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
            }
        }

        // func that returns the cell attributes for the elements that are visible in the screen
        override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

            // Create an array to hold all elements found in our current view.
            var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

            // Check each element to see if it should be returned.
            for cellAttributes in cellAttrsDictionary {
                if rect.intersects(cellAttributes.frame) {
                    attributesInRect.append(cellAttributes)
                }
            }

            // Return list of elements.
            return attributesInRect
        }

        //func that returns the cell attributes for the indexpath
        override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
            return cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath.row]
        }

        //this func call the prepare func if the user scrolls if returned true
        override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: `seatNo += 1` Definitely not good. If you scroll down, it's "fine", but if you scroll up after, `seatNo` will increase each time (because the cellForRowAtItem will be called again). Why not using instead `indexPath.row+1` instead?

Comment: it works for the mentioned code. but if we want to assign different values    that are not in sequence or are stored in a array. Then what should be the approach.

Comment: Consider that you have `var array:[Int]` for the seats numbers that you populate, they `let seatNumber = array[indexPath.row]`

Comment: thanks for the help it will resolve the issue for me.

Comment: i am stuck into another issue now each seat has a price so i took a price variable in the cell class. Now i have a array of prices like this var price = [200, 300, 400] and i want to assign the first 3 rows with the first value next 5 with the second value and the rest with the third value of the price array. How to achieve this

Comment: Instead, use a custom class let's call it Seat, with a number property and a price one. And use it in the array. Then `let seatNumber = array[indexPath.row].pricePropertyName; let price = array[indexPath.row].price`

Comment: my seat Map is created by the help of you approach and all the values are being displayed properly in the map. I had put selection to the seats so that user can select the seats and i had also disabled some of the cells. Every thing works fine but when i scroll the map right and left for several times some cells that are expected to be selectable are not being able to be selected. What could be the reason for that @Larme if you want i can update the code.

Comment: Each time there is an `if` in `cellForItemAt`, don't forget to implement the else with the "reverse value" (like show image/hide image). Also, keep update your `SeetMap` to whenever there is a change (like selected, etc.)

Comment: @Larme i tried doing what you said but the issue still persists. even if i am not disabling any user interaction then also some cells are not clickable. I tried even removing the `didSelectItemAt` and `didDeselectItemAt`.  Should i update the code for you to have a look at what is wrong

Comment: I removed some properties from the `prepareForReuse()` function and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using an array, why not say

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


    let seatNo = (indexPath.row + 1) + (indexPath.section * 15) 
    cell.assignSeat(seat: seatNo)
    cell.seatNumber.text = "\(cell.seat ?? 0)"
    return cell
}
```

I haven't ran this code but the idea is to use

```
indexPath.row + 1
```

to get the seats position in its row.

then we can use

```
indexPath.section * 15 // (number of seats per row should be declared static)
```

to get the count of seats in the previous rows to this one. in the first row the section will be 0 so won't add anything but subsequent rows will be added correctly

I highly advise declaring the 15 and 10 at the top of your file to avoid magic numbers